# Topic not consumable, broker not available if one broker removed

Tags: apache-kafka

If I remove one broker in a two broker cluster, I observe that the topic is sometimes no longer consumable even though the replication factor is two. Here's my setup:

Node #1:

```
process.roles=broker,controller
node.id=1
controller.quorum.voters=1@192.168.56.1:9093
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.56.1:9092,CONTROLLER://192.168.56.1:9093
num.partitions=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
```

Node #2:

```
process.roles=broker
node.id=2
controller.quorum.voters=1@192.168.56.1:9093
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.56.101:9092
num.partitions=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=2
```

Here's what I observe:

- If I create a topic, `my-topic`, I observe that topic's directory is created either in `kraft-combined-logs/` folder in either node 1 or node 2, but not both
- If the topic's directory is created on node 2, and I stop the broker on that node, a `kafka-console-consumer` connected to the broker on node 1 for the topic no longer receives messages and starts printing these logs:

```
WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-53567] Connection to node 2 (/192.168.56.101:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

- After broker 2 is brought back up, the consumer starts functionally normally and receives any messages that it missed while broker 2 was down
- If the topic's directory is created on node 1, and I stop the broker on node 2, a `kafka-console-consumer` connected to the broker on node 1 for the topic functions normally. It prints any messages that a `kafka-console-producer` creates

Does this mean the topic is not replicated across brokers? How can I continue to have the consumer consume messages while broker 2 is down? I am running in KRaft mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set `default.replication.factor=2`. This seems obvious, but the `server.properties` shipped with Kafka does not have this setting. After setting this, the topic file is replicated on two nodes.